# adding com.android.support:design:28.0.0 dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, material-components-android, android-support-design

I am trying to add Floating Edit text to my app. For this have added 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' dependency to my build.gradle (;app).
I'm getting this following error if  try to run the project.
if  need to refactor>Migrate to androidX :(please guide me to the process)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this dependency since you are using the **Material components library** (it is a drop-in replacement for Android's Design Support Library).

Just **remove** it.

Comment: okay i'll go with that, so should i remove jcenter() or keep it as it is ?

Comment: you can keep it for the end of the year... some libraries depends on it/